# How do you change the namespace of the serialized message in NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I've tried adding the appSetting "NameSpace" to my publisher and subscriber but the messages still contain the namespace http://tempuri.org/...

**[Edit]**

In the publisher EndpointConfig I have added:

```
public class ServerInit : IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With().XmlSerializer("http://foo.com");
    }
}
```

This works but I would rather see this in the config file. Please let me know if anyone can suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just put that in your app settings and pull it using the .net configuration manager.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Udi, I noticed that the distributor reads this from the appSettings already, just wondered why the others don't.

Comment: Because it's not something that should be possible for an administrator to accidentally change in your app. The distributor has it exposed so that you won't need to recompile it.